# Relay: Composing child fragments

Tags: reactjs, react-router, relayjs

With react-router:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="help" component={Help} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

And in App:

```
render() {
 return (
   {this.props.children}
  );
}
```

If on the App container I compose the fragments of the children

```
${About.getFragment(somefragment)}
${Help.getFragment(someFragment)}
```

Will relay compose the fragments given that the components are expressed as children with {this.props.children} and not instantiated from their classes with ,  ?

The question is does using children with the syntax {this.props.children} work with relay's aggregating fragment logic?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, however it's not best practice to store all your fragments in the highest parent-level component. With Relay, the idea is that you want to declare your data requirements alongside your components instantiated with their classes. That way, you know exactly what data is being fetched from the GraphQL server for each component, maintaining separation of concerns for each component, also creating less confusion.